# Why is TabContainer not in my list of available AJAX controls?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've got this legacy app I'm dealing with, and for reasons too lengthy to explain I'm forced to deal with this in VS2010.  I want to add a TabContainer to a page, but it's not in my list of available AJAX controls.  In fact, the only ones showing up in the list in my toolbox are Pointer, ScripManager, ScriptManagerProxy, Timer, UpdatePanel and UpdateProgress.

How do I get TabContainer in my toolbox in VS2010 (specifically in C#)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to update your toolkit http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Install-AJAX-Control-Toolkit-in-Visual-Studio-ToolBox.aspx